# Excel WorksheetFunction.Trend function in VBA

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have the formula =TREND({4000,20000},{0,32},B15) in an Excel cell.

What is the correct way to use this in a VBA function?

I keep getting Runtime Error 1004: Unable to get the Trend property of the WorksheetFunction class, whenever Itry variations along the lines of:

WorksheetFunction.Trend("{4000,20000}", "{0,32}", "B15")

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get your formula to work in an Excel cell (#REF error). Don't the known x's have to have the same number of values as the known y's? This worked

```
?application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(array(4000,20000),array(0.30,0.32),Range("B15").Value)(1)
```

I'm using the array function to create arrays for the first two arguments. I made up another value for the second argument. The whole thing then returns an array, so the `(1)` at the end is to return the first element of the array.

You can inspect the result with a sub like this

```
Sub TestTrend()

    Dim aY(1 To 2) As Double
    Dim aX(1 To 2) As Double
    Dim vResult As Variant

    Range("B15").Value = 0.35

    aY(1) = 4000: aY(2) = 20000
    aX(1) = 0.3: aX(2) = 0.32

    vResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trend(aY, aX, Range("B15").Value)

    Stop

End Sub
```

When you View - Locals, you can see that the result holds a one-element variant array.

[image: VBE - View - Locals]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd tried the array() function, but I'd omitted the terminal (1).